Cryptography in the symmetric group
I'm looking for a way for two players $P_1$ and $P_2$, only interacting with each other, to come up with elements $g_1,g_1',g_2,g_2'\in \Sigma_n$ such that

$g_1g_2=g_2'g_1'$;
For each $i=1,2$, $P_i$ sees all possible values of $g_1g_2$ (i.e. all of $\Sigma_n$) as equally likely to occur. In other words, $P_i$ knows as much information as if instead they had chosen the $g_i,g_i'$ independently and some trusted third party had suddenly said to them


$P_j$ has chosen $g_j,g_j'$ such that
$$g_1g_2 = g_2'g_1'$$

(where $j=3-i$).
It'd be great if some one could help me with this purpose.
Motivation:
This could be used to design a cryptographic deck of cards from which both players can draw cards privately or publicly by revealing no nontrivial information about the undrawn cards.
Here $n=52$ and we number the cards from $1$ to $52$. Then the $m$-th card of the shuffled deck will be $K(m)$ where $K=g_1g_2$. Now, suppose $P_1$ wants to draw the $m$-th card of the deck. Then $P_2$ sends $g_2(m)$ to $P_1$ who then calculates $g_1(g_2(m))=K(m)$. If $P_2$ wants to draw a card, $P_1$ sends $g_1'(m)$ to $P_2$ who calculates $g_2'(g_1'(m))=K(m)$.
One can check that with this protocol, no information is gained by hearing the intermediate values $g_2(m),g_1'(m)$. Of course the player drawing privately a card from the deck will gain info about what's (not) in the deck but that's part of the game.
Thanks in advance.
